# Generic HTTP server that just dumps POST requests?

Tags: http, http-logging

I am looking for a command line tool that listens on a given part, happily excepts every HTTP POST request and dumps it.

I want to use it for testing purposes, i.e. for testing clients that issue HTTP POST requests.

That means I am searching the counterpart to `curl -F` (which I can use to send test HTTP POSTs to a HTTP server).

Perhaps something like `socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 ...` - but socat is not enough because it does not talk HTTP.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question correctly, but if all you need is to dump the POST request, you can use `netcat` (`nc` on some systems) with the `-l` (listen) and `-p` (port number) options.

Comment: @peterph, you can use `nc` for partial testing - but I can see following disadvantages: 1) it does not send HTTP status code 2) I have to hit Ctrl+D after I see the request to close the connection 3) it does not know how to react upon then 'Expect: 100-continue' header 4) it does not know how to handle the 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' header - it probably just displays the first (probably) empty chunk

Comment: Similar question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-that-accepts-get-post-calls

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple core command line tools like `nc`, `socat` seem not to be able to handle the specific HTTP stuff going on (chunks, transfer encodings, etc.). As a result this may produce unexpected behaviour compared to talking to a real web server. So, my first thought is to share the quickest way I know of setting up a tiny web server and making it just do what you want: dump all output.

The shortest I could come up with using [Python Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import pprint

class MyDumpHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        pprint.pprint(self.request)
        pprint.pprint(self.request.body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.web.Application([(r"/.*", MyDumpHandler),]).listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Replace the `pprint` line to output only the specific fields you need, for example `self.request.body` or `self.request.headers`. In the example above it listens on port 8080, on all interfaces.

Alternatives to this are plenty. [web.py](http://webpy.org/), [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), etc.

<sup>(I'm quite Python oriented, sorry)</sup>

---

If you don't like its way of outputting, just run it anyway and try `tcpdump` like this:

```
tcpdump -i lo 'tcp[32:4] = 0x484f535420'
```

to see a real raw dump of all HTTP-POST requests. Alternatively, just run Wireshark.

Comment: For others who find this very helpful snippet - it does what was asked - but if you want to see the POST body, it's `pprint.pprint(self.request.body)`.  Note `self.request.body` rather than `self.body`.  Same for `self.request.headers`. See http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.request

Comment: FWIW, even without tornado, with just the Python standard library, such a minimal dumper would be just 3 lines or so longer. See also [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709408/1131) - it supports more request types, json dumping and command line parsing, thus, it's a bit longer - but when restricting it to raw POST requests like this you just need to explicitly read the request body and send a status code, as additional work.

Answer (score 72):

I was looking for this myself as well and [ran into the Node.js http-echo-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-echo-server):

```
npm install http-echo-server -g
PORT=8081 http-echo-server
```

It accepts all requests and echos the full request including header to the command-line.

Answer (score 8):

Use `nc` (pronounced "[netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)").

You tell it which port to listen on

```bash
nc -kl 8888
```

Then in a separate terminal window send a request to it

```bash
curl localhost:8888 -d hello=world
```

and it will print the data you sent in to it, in this case an HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

hello=world
```

The `-k` option means it will listen for requests and print them indefinitely. Without that option (i.e. `nc -l 8888`), it will exit after the first request.

Comment: You nc command doesn't speak HTTP. Thus, an HTTP client (here the curl command)  blocks on waiting for the HTTP-server's reply (such as some common status code) that never comes.

Answer (score 5):

https://hub.docker.com/r/jmalloc/echo-server/

Run

```bsh
$ docker run -t --rm -p 8080:8080 jmalloc/echo-server
Unable to find image 'jmalloc/echo-server:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from jmalloc/echo-server
fbf67b0844fa: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:617a99b927c3b761621681eb4716582260391c0853b6da904e0f9f1d37785e7a
Status: Downloaded newer image for jmalloc/echo-server:latest
Echo server listening on port 8080
```

Post

```bsh
$ curl -XPOST -H"ThisTook: 2 minutes to find" localhost:8080/asdf
Request served by a2d8fa109b92

HTTP/1.1 POST /asdf

Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Thistook: 2 minutes to find
```

Comment: That docker container just contains a single binary, so you can also `docker cp <cid>:/bin/echo-server .` to grab the binary.

Comment: And do what with it.. and why?

Comment: run it on your Linux server, since the author doesn't have precompiled binaries.

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding intent here - you want to cp a binary from a docker instance/container and run it directly on the host? As opposed to running it in the container, which is a controlled environment that satisfies any/all needed dependencies of said binary?

Comment: The binary can be put on random servers you're debugging that don't have docker installed, and you don't have to mess with the pain that is docker networking.

Comment: Docker networking..? First, if you don't have docker installed, using a binary from a container is not a workaround: the binary is compiled against a cpu architecture and a set of predefined dependencies, all of which the docker context is providing, of which there is little to NO chance you'll just happen to have on bare metal. Second, you need an interface:port to resolve http\s requests, which, if the originating request is on the same machine is localhost:$port and if not, $host:$port: in both cases, you can bind the container to the host port space, which has nothing to do with..

Comment: containers being networked on some shared subnet

Comment: It's a go binary, there are no external dependencies, it's statically linked like virtually all go binaries.

Comment: That's cool, to bring up months later and for the first time; statically linked, or not, doesn't mean "works on alpine" or "works on anything that it wasn't specifically compiled against (see link)". The reason I am being a dick is because wtf are you pulling a binary out of a container, as opposed to just running the binary in the gd container? Dockerd is universally available, bulletproofed ad nauseam, etc etc. https://gist.github.com/asukakenji/f15ba7e588ac42795f421b48b8aede63

Comment: This does not answer the question: the server does not output what is POSTed to it, just the fact that a POST occurred. #Took2MinutesToCheck

Answer (score 4):

The Python standard library comes with batteries included, i.e. it even includes an HTTP server package that can be used to write a simple HTTP request dumper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import http.server
import json
import sys

class Dumper(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self, method='GET'):
        print(f'\n{method} {self.path}\n{self.headers}')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_DELETE(self):
        return self.do_GET('DELETE')

    def do_POST(self, method='POST'):
        n = int(self.headers.get('content-length', 0))
        body = self.rfile.read(n)
        print(f'\n{method} {self.path}\n{self.headers}{body}\n')
        if self.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
            d = json.loads(body)
            print(json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            print()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_PUT(self):
        return self.do_POST('PUT')

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        pass
```

Some boilerplate:

```
def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dump HTTP requests to stdout')
    p.add_argument('address', help='bind address')
    p.add_argument('port', type=int, help='bind port')
    xs = p.parse_args();
    s = http.server.HTTPServer((xs.address, xs.port), Dumper)
    s.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

See also: [my gist](https://gist.github.com/gsauthof/276a6ca1bd28231dce20f60159f1f569)